# How to disable or change the behavior or Fn+S?

Tags: fedora, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a LG Gram 16 and I'm used to Thinkpad that have Fn and Ctrl keys inversed.

I always press Fn+S thinking it's Ctrl-S to save files but it's actually putting my computer to sleep... Very annoying.

There is no setting in the bios to inverse Fn/Ctrl and no way to disable that.

What's the workaround for Linux? (gnome, RHEL, Fedora)

Comment: In many laptop keyboards, the Fn key doesn't report to the OS, only the final combo (unless handled by firmware). If that's your case, I'm not sure you can do anything about it. If you can get the  (X11) `xev` utility to detect using the Fn key alone, mention it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The command localectl may allow you to change keyboard settings. However, I have not personally tried it.

localectl is a command-line utility in Linux systems that is part of the systemd suite. It is used to query and change system locale and keyboard layout settings. The systemd suite is a set of system management daemons, libraries, and utilities designed to provide a central management framework for Linux systems.

good lack!